# Move Search Box in Typo3 V6.2.5 List Module (Backend)

Tags: typo3, backend, extbase

I'm using an own Extbase extension with my articles, which are stored in a Sysfolder.
 
It is possible to move the Search Box in the Backend's List module from the bottom to the top?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible since the html is not located in a template but is  `hardcoded` located in the `\TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\RecordList::main()` function (see: `typo3/sysext/recordlist/Classes/RecordList.php`).

I don't know if the back-end has a `contentPostProc-all` `hook`. If some kind of hook exists you can move the html by your own class.